Websocket with socket.io on K8S, how to make it work?
I hope you are well
I'm having a problem when trying to open communication between my applications within Kubernetes. Currently client-server communicate through socket.io, but when adding it to kubernetes, I am having the following problem: server and client connect, I can know that they do from the server log, but no event exchange occurs!
I've searched everywhere on the internet, but the solutions I found were for GKE, and I'm running a cluster created by kubeadm, so they're not usable. Has anyone gone through something similar to this?
Some questions I can ask:

Server pod is running normally, it responds to http requests through ingress
I am using ingress-nginx v1.10.0 to expose my service
My application is: Client made in Angular and server in Spring boot, talking through socket.io.
There is nothing special in the services and deployments manifest declaration, just the basics for it to work.
My ingress manifest:

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dpiot
  annotations:
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: dpiot-back-service
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: dpiotfront.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: dpiot-front-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /socket.io/
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: dpiot-back-service
            port:
              number: 80

I've been searching for more than hours and no results, I'm running out of options, if anyone can help me I would be very grateful. Any additional information you need for something, just ask!
Cluster information:
Kubernetes version: 1.29.0
Cloud being used: bare-metal
Installation method: kubeadm
Host OS: CentOS 7
CNI and version: Calico
CRI and version: Containerd

you need to add something like this to your Kubernetes Ingress configuration:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
   proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

